# Output graph as `.xml`

Tags: python, xml, networkx

I have a shapefile that I am converting to an `.xml` file for use in MATSim. The file structure is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE network SYSTEM "http://www.matsim.org/files/dtd/network_v1.dtd">
<network name="VISUM export national network 2007-11-28">

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <nodes>
        <node id="1000" x="730065.3125" y="220415.9531" type="2" origid="1000" />
        <node id="1001" x="731010.5" y="220146.2969" type="2" origid="1001" />
        .....
    </nodes>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <links capperiod="01:00:00" effectivecellsize="7.5" effectivelanewidth="3.75">
        <link id="100365" from="226" to="227" length="921.0" freespeed="33.3333333333333" capacity="5600.0" permlanes="2.0" oneway="1" modes="car" origid="183" type="10" />
    ...
    </links>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
</network>
```

I'm doing this with the NetworkX Python library, which can read shapefiles as a graph, and export the graph as a `GEXF` object. This code (essentially), outputs something close to, but not close enough, to the network specification.

```python
import networkx as nx

G = nx.read_shp("expcuts1.shp")
start = 0
G = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G, first_label=start, 
        label_attribute = "coord")

# Build a new object with the elements that you need
H = nx.DiGraph(name = "Python NetworkX export from FAF 3.4")
H.add_edges_from(G.edges())

# store coordinates in node attributes
for i in range(len(H)):
    H.node[i]['x'] = G.node[i]['coord'][0]
    H.node[i]['y'] = G.node[i]['coord'][1]

# export as xml (really, gexl, but that's pretty close)
nx.write_gexf(H, 'test.xml')
```

```xml
<gexf version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft" xmlns:viz="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft/viz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <graph defaultedgetype="undirected" mode="static">
    <attributes class="node" mode="static">
      <attribute id="0" title="y" type="double" />
      <attribute id="1" title="x" type="double" />
    </attributes>
    <nodes>
      <node id="0" label="0">
        <attvalues>
          <attvalue for="0" value="1389860.27495" />
          <attvalue for="1" value="2237913.99085" />
        </attvalues>
      </node>
```

In addition to this, the GEXL uses nodes and *edges*, but the MATSim vocabulary asks for nodes and *links*. I'm trying to decide whether it would be easier to tweak the `write_gexf` function from NetworkX or to write out to XML manually, for instance with the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Any tips?

Comment: Can you say with certainty that the graph is acyclic? If not, what should be done about cycles?

Comment: The graph is most certainly cyclical; it represents a highway network. The graph doesn't necessarily need to be directed, though. I can create `H` as either a `Graph` or a `DiGraph` and the output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Short: Tweak the `write_gexf` function from NetworkX, if this is a one-time project.

Long:

For MATSim you'll need a directed graph. Gexf allows for that `defaultedgetype="directed"`. You can add further attributes to the edges, e.g. capacity, lanes...

```
<edge weight="1.0" target="109001663" source="109001672" label="network link" id="99999">
 <attvalues>
  <attvalue start="0.0" value="0" for="capacity"/>
  <attvalue start="0.0" value="0" for="length"/>
 </attvalues>
</edge>
```

Since you already have a gexf the last step is a one-to-one conversion. Gexf nodes directly translate to MATSim nodes whereas the edges are links in MATSim terminology. However, you need the provide MATSim with the network's attributes.

Nodes just need the x,y-coordinate

For links you may want to add the actual length of the link (not the Euclidean distance). Furthermore, you'll need the maximum allowed speed (freespeed), the capacity (usually given in [PCU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_car_equivalent) per hour), and the number of lanes.

Note that the capacity depends on the capperiod, i.e. `capperiod="01:00:00"` means valid for one hour.

P.S. You can also have a look at [the gexf package](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/matsim/code/playgrounds/trunk/vsp/src/main/java/playground/vsp/gexf/) where you'll find some gexf helper classes mainly for converting MATSim networks to gexf, e.g. for analyzing them in Gephi.